# Loop over each line of text file in bash

Tags: bash, text

Here's what the text looks like:

```
428, "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqlJl1LfDP4", "NEW YORK,NEW YORK- FRANK SINATRA - YouTube", "moc.ebutuoy.www.", 1, 0, 0, 20, 96, 1329427038818198, "aiODk063S1YW" 
429, "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIiUqfxFttM&feature=list_related&playnext=1&list=AVGxdCwVVULXfJnKOaSACBmNaC6ZZ71zS7", "Frank Sinatra - That's Life - YouTube", "moc.ebutuoy.www.", 1, 0, 0, 20, 96, 1329427228164029, "96X5yyV88p8v"
```

---

```
id,url,title,...unnecessary info...
```

I want to grab each row of a text file in a bash script. Get the second parameter (url), and then patch that into a script.

I'm not really sure how to loop for each line, and then pull out that second param.

Thanks

Comment: Try [get-flash-videos](http://code.google.com/p/get-flash-videos/).

Comment: I'm not asking how to download them, I'm asking how to loop it in bash. I already have a youtube to mp3 script set up.

Comment: OK. You'll probably need `read` (a Bash builtin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for URL in $(cut -d, -f2 < file)
do
    echo $URL
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -f 2 -d " " thefile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**Print the second argument of each line:**

```
awk '{ print $2 }' thefile.txt
```

To use it in a script (i.e. loop over it):

```
for URL in `awk '{ print $2 }' thefile.txt`
do
    echo $URL
done
```

One important thing to note is that the `"` and `,` will be included in the URL.

If you want to remove these, just grab the substring of the 2nd argument:

```
awk '{ print substr( $2, 2, length($2) -3 ) }' thefile.txt
```

We start at the 2nd character on the line, and show the full length -3 of the line.

In a loop:

```
for URL in `awk '{ print substr( $2, 2, length($2) -3 ) }' thefile.txt`
do
    echo $URL
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Oli's answer, you can remove beginning `"` and final `",` using sed:

```
cut -f 2 -d " " thefile.txt | sed -e "s/^\"//" -e "s/\"\,$//"
```