# How to stream input line by line in UNIX, perform commands on each line, and immediately return output?

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to do something very simple, but solving it the way I want would help me with many other commands as well.

I want to read a file line by line in UNIX and perform commands on them, in this case character count. For an entire file, I would just use:

```
wc -m
```

However, I want this per line of input. What is the simplest, shortest way to stream a file line by line for manipulation by UNIX commands? I ask because in this situation I want wc -m per line, but future applications will use completely different commands.

Also, I want to avoid perl and awk! I already know how to do this with those tools, but am looking for alternate methods.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Thanks for the link to the other question, but after looking at their 4 answers, I don't see a solution to my exact quandary.

Given the following input:

```
cat test.txt
    This is the first line.
    This is the second, longer line.
    This is short.
    My Final line that is much longer than the first couple of lines.
```

I want to plug it through some code that will read it line by line and perform a command on each line, immediately returning the result.

Some code which does `wc -m` on each line and returns the output:

```
23
32
14
65
```

Or some code which does `cut -d " " -f 1` on each line and returns the output:

```
This
This
This
My
```

Hopefully this makes things a bit clearer. Thanks again for any suggestions!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop over each line of text file in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353882/loop-over-each-line-of-text-file-in-bash)

Comment: Its hard to visualize what you expect the output. Can you include some simple sample input and expected output from that input? Good luck.

Comment: Sure, will do. Am editing question now...

Comment: just thinking... maybe `sed` could be of use? For example, if I use sed -n '2p' file.txt | wc -m, it grabs the second line and does `wc -m`. Could this be iterated for each line instead of just line 2?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `echo "${#line}"` to know the length of a string. Reading the file with a `while read...` will do the rest:

```
$ cat file
hello
my name
is fedor
qui


$ while read line; do echo "${#line}"; done < file
5
7
8
3
0
```

In a nicer format:

```
while read line
do
   echo "${#line}"
done < file
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This is very close to what I'm looking for, but not quite. I want to be able to use any UNIX command per line of input with the results immediately returned. In this case your code works because you are using `${#line}`, but if I use `wc -m` I get the total characters in the file. I want something that will work with any UNIX command!

Comment: Answers provided are as specific as you are in your question. So try to be more specific... why `${#line}` is not going to be useful?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake for not being specific enough when I asked. I have since revised my question. I am not really interested in just character count, but instead a general mechanism for line-by-line streaming for use with any UNIX command.

Comment: Well I am afraid I cannot think on another method. This one matches your requirement *I want to plug it through some code that will read it line by line and perform a command on each line, immediately returning the result*. Maybe someone else can give further help!

Comment: @jake9115, I think, you seek adding `xargs` to this
`somestream | while read line; do echo $line | xargs -n1 wc -m; done` I usually grep/sed/log infinity streams this method

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for line-by-line processing is a `while read` loop, although the idiom to use to preserve the lines exactly is:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # process "$line"
done
```

Failing to use `IFS=` will lose leading whitespace. Failing to use `read -r` means some backslash sequences will be interpreted by bash and not kept verbatim in the variable.

I think your quandry can be restated:

> I have a line of text. How do I treat it like a file?

bash has 2 features that can answer that

1. for commands like `wc` that can read from stdin, use a [here-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings):

   ```
   wc -m <<< "$line"
   ```
2. for commands that require a file (I can't think of one off the top of my head), use a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

   ```
   wc -m <(echo "$line")
   ```

Example:

```
$ line="foo bar baz"
$ wc -m <<<"$line"
12
$ wc -m <(echo "$line")
12 /dev/fd/63
```

p.s.
I notice the char count includes the implicit trailing newline. To remove that, use printf without a newline in the format string

```
$ wc -m <(printf %s "$line")
11 /dev/fd/63
$ wc -m < <(printf %s "$line")
11
```